# CSS sliding-door buttons center alignment

Tags: css, button, alignment, sliding-doors

I need help to align CSS buttons. I tried many different variations and I just cannot center my button the way I want.

Firstly, have a look at this url: http://www.front-end-developer.net/cssbuttons/example.htm

I'm using 2 images to form a button (this could be done on 1 image, but in this case we've got two). Everything works as expected as long as we apply `float:left` or `float:right` to the parent div element, to 'limit' width of the div and close it as soon as the content of the div ends. You can remove float:left from the button to see what I mean.

But what about center positioned buttons? I cannot add float:left/right because I want align it in the middle.

In theory, I could set

```
{
    width:XXpx;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And I will get what you can see on this picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [front-end-developer.net](http://www.front-end-developer.net/cssbuttons/cssbuttonerror.png))</sub>

But I don't know the length of the text inside. Having different translations my button can be very short, or 5 times that long.

I also tried to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`, but unfortunately nested inline elements don't respect their padding correctly...

And yes, I must use `<a>` inside, so buttons can be accessed by web crawlers.

I'm really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.button {display:inline-block;}
```

Seems to do the trick.

inline-block browser-support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

More about how to work around the browser issues related to inline-block:
http://foohack.com/2007/11/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block-styling/

Comment: as per my comment in other answer - inline-block doesn't work on IE6 and IE7 that's why I knew I can't use it.

But your link to cross-browser inline block fix resolves this issue! Sneaky way, but hey, it works. thanks a lot