# css right-to-left sliding doors

Tags: css, sliding-doors

I am trying to do navigation menu, using sliding doors technique.
my site is right-to-left aligned.

does anybody know how to make it work, aligned from right to left??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these.
[CSS sliding-door buttons center alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471802/css-sliding-door-buttons-center-alignment)

http://www.meekostuff.net/blog/CSS-Sliding-Doors/

Hope it helps,